# Generate certs for Integrating GitLab CI with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I want to integrate GitLab CI with Kubernetes and I need to fill up the config.toml file. Do you have any idea how can I generate these certificates?

cert_file: Optional Kubernetes apiserver user auth certificate

key_file: Optional Kubernetes apiserver user auth private key

ca_file: Optional Kubernetes apiserver ca certificate

Comment: Hi  Mihaela, welcome to S.F. Are you certain those are the only supported authentication mechanisms? Usually [GL to k8s connectivity is via a Service Account Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_remove_clusters.html#existing-kubernetes-cluster), which is a JWT, not a keypair. Can you edit your question and provide a link to the docs for the file you are trying to populate?

Comment: Hi, the link for the docs is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerskubernetes-section

Comment: What a surprising oversight on their part; are you running the GitLab Runner inside the kubernetes cluster as they recommend?